# Is this a topological $\mathbb Z_2$ (Majorana-)invariant in *any* dimension?

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators, majorana-fermions, topological-phase

Consider a non-interacting superconducting Hamiltonian in an arbitrary dimension. This is most conveniently expressed in terms of Majorana modes, which are defined as $$\gamma_{2n-1} = c_n + c_n^\dagger \quad \textrm{ and } \quad\gamma_{2n} = -i \left( c_n - i c_n^\dagger \right)$$
for every complex fermionic mode $c_n$. For convenience we label $n = 1, 2, \cdots N$ where $N$ is our number of sites, but I am not presuming a one-dimensional structure (i.e. I do not enforce a notion of locality with respect to this labeling). A generic Hamiltonian is then written as
$$ H = i \sum_{n,m} \gamma_n A_{nm} \gamma_m $$
where $A \in \mathbb R^{2N}\times \mathbb R^{2N}$ is anti-symmetric: $A^T = - A$.

Requiring a gap above the ground state is equivalent to demanding that $\det A\neq 0$. (Indeed: the positive eigenvalues of $A$ tell us the single-particle excitation energies.) But in that case the sign of the Pfaffian of $A$ is a well-defined quantity (i.e. $\frac{\textrm{pf} A}{\sqrt{\det A}}$).

**This seemingly gives a topological $\mathbb Z_2$ invariant, independent of dimensionality!** But this must be wrong, since the classification of non-interacting topological insulators/superconductors tells us this class of Hamiltonians (`class D') only has a $\mathbb Z_2$ invariant when the dimension of space is $d = 1 \mod 8$.

Answer (score 1):

[Disclaimer: I find the conclusion a bit surprising, so perhaps it is provisional, but I do not see any other way out.]

As Kitaev (cf. equation (19) of his [seminal paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0010440.pdf)) pointed out, the above $\mathbb Z_2$ invariant in fact simply equals the fermionic parity (= parity of the number of fermions) of the ground state, i.e. $P|\psi\rangle = \pm |\psi\rangle$. This is consistent with what we know of the Kitaev/Majorana chain: with closed boundary conditions, the fermionic parity of the ground state is $-1$.

This makes it clear that the above $\mathbb Z_2$ invariant is indeed well-defined in *any dimension*! The only way out must be: in e.g. dimensions $d=3,4,5,7$ (for which the `D class' only has a trivial phase according to the classification table, cf Table 3 of [the paper by Ryu et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.2157.pdf)) it must be impossible to write down a Hamiltonian for which the ground state has an odd number of fermions. (There would have to be some conditions on this to make it precise: e.g. '*for an even number of sites*', '*with a well-defined thermodynamic limit*', ...)

**In summary:** *the $\mathbb Z_2$ invariant is indeed well-defined, but one cannot always find an example which realizes a non-trival value.*

Comment: Consider the much easier example of the complex classes of the table: one can always define a winding number, but it is non-zero only if the BZ is of odd dimension.

Comment: For sure you can find systems of odd parity in any dimension: simply stack Kitaev chains on top of each other in a suitable way. This could hint at a resolution: Not all invariants manifest themselves in the same way on the boundary. In particular the groups in the periodic table are *strong* invariants, associated to top dim cycles in the BZ (in non-interacting, translation invariant physics). There are many more *weak* invariants associated to lower dim ones.